# Web Page Is Scrolled Half Way Down When Loading on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I'm having an issue with a long-scroll website I'm working on.  Currently, when I load the page on my iPhone, the initial scroll position appears half way down or near the bottom of the page the majority of the time.  I have tried disabling a few of the slide shows, etc. on the page to try to isolate the problem, but I've had no luck.

I'm sure this is caused either by the way I'm loading in JavaScript or my stylesheets.

If anyone could take a look at this page and see if you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it:

http://www.ideabasekent.com/staging/athletics2015/

Comment: Does this happen only on refresh?

Comment: It also happens at the first page load - I've tried clearing the cache and reloading - still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and i figure out that you're loading CSS files using javascript. It's not a good practice to lazy load CSS files because browsers needs to read CSS file before render the page to know exactly where every element must be. Try to put your CSS using metatags instead of loading with javascript.

Comment: And this link to CSS file is broken:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.min.css?newer" media="all">`

Comment: I had thought this might be part of the issue, but I tried turning off the lazy load and it doesn't seem to help.  I'm inlining my critical CSS in the Head of the document - trying to prevent "render blocking".

Comment: Just turned off CSS lazy loading and put in a link tag instead - it's still intermittently scrolling down to the bottom of the page on load.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your javascript files, but they're all minified, so it's hard to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - I had an accordion script that was scrolling the page down.  I disabled that option and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this due to anchor links on my page. If you refresh the page on iPhone after clicking on an anchor link, it will navigate to the anchor link.

Answer (score 0):

For me (August 2022, iOS 15.6), fixing the meta viewport tag helped.

I replaced this:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

with

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```